# How to use Router isActive to determine if a term is in the url?

Tags: angular

say I have two routes that use the same component:

```
   {
     path: 'search',                                                               
     loadChildren: () => import('../search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchModule)                  
    },
```

and

```
   {
     path: 'items/:id/search',                                                               
     loadChildren: () => import('../search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchModule)                  
    },
```

I was thinking that the component could know if a search is being performed, by doing:

```
this.router.isActive('search', { matrixParams: 'ignored', queryParams: 'ignored', paths: 'subset', fragment: 'ignored' })
```

But it only returns true when it's on the `search` route and not the `items/123/search` route ...  Can I get isActive to also return true for the latter?